# Request mac address of network devices

Tags: android, networking, kotlin, mac-address

I'm running an app that talks to a server (that sometimes changes it's ip ) and to be sure it's connected to the right server, I have to query the mac address from the server.

The server and Android device are on the same network and I'm forced to use DHCP for my server.

Is there any way to do such thing and is it applicable to Android?

Thanks

Comment: "_i'm forced to use DHCP for my server_" You should then use DHCP reservations so that the server is always assigned the same address by DHCP.

Comment: but .. it can't , it's often restarted and there is a lot of devices on the network
can DHCP reservation help me with that ?

Comment: Yes. With a reservation, the DHCP server will always give the same IP address for a particular MAC address. That was designed for your specific problem.

Comment: Ok so my problem is near to be solved , but I may , for many other projects have to querry that mac adress ,some programs like "advanced ip scanner" are doing really well

Comment: It isn't designed that way. You should look at multicast. A device can subscribe to a particular multicast address, then a different host can send a query to the multicast address, and the host subscribing to that address can respond. You are then independent of the particular network or host address.

Comment: Do not get hung up on your particular idea of a solution. That leads to the [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about the real problem, not the solution, then you will get answers that can solve the original problem.

Comment: yeah I might try to do a list of the servers and make the user choose the right one ... but i thought letting the user enter a mac address would be more secure

Comment: Dynamic DNS is another option if you have DNS set up on that network.

Comment: Do not try to equate a MAC address with security. That is a false sense of security as it is very simple to change a MAC address on a machine to any allowed MAC address. Never, ever use an address (MAC, IP, etc.) for security, it is worse than no security because you think you have security, but you have none.

Comment: ok this was not really for secure purposes but more like choosing the right server But thak you for the advice i didn't knew